# logging action done via RabbitMQ management

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-management

is there an easy way to audit/log logging action done via RabbitMQ management?
for instance, a user entered the RabbitMQ management and published a message through it, I would like to be able to know who published the message and when.
Assume I'm using LDAP for authentication.

thanks!